# using jsoup to modify data

Tags: coldfusion, jsoup, lucee

i have successfully used and got html from the website, i am having some troubles while showing the Data

Here is my generated code

```
<tr class="2" id="AS 2238_2022-10-18T08:50:00"> <td id=" Air"> <img src="/webfids/logos/AS.jpg" width="138" height="31" title=" Air" alt=" Air"> </td> <td id="2238"> 2238</td> <td id="Phoenix"> Phoenix</td> <td id="1666108200000"> 8:50A&nbsp;10-18-22</td> <td id="AS 2238_2022-10-18T08:50:00_status"> <font class="default"> On Time </font></td> <td id="AS 2238_2022-10-18T08:50:00_gate">2A</td> <td id="AS 2238_2022-10-18T08:50:00_terminal">&nbsp;</td> <td id="AS 2238_2022-10-18T08:50:00_codeShares">&nbsp;</td> <td id="AS 2238_2022-10-18T08:50:00_CDS">&nbsp;</td> <td id="marker" style="display: none">0</td> </tr>
```

i am trying to remove the last TD of every row, i have many rowd, i am running over the loop

here is my code

```
rows = TheTable.select("tr");

for ( row in rows ){
    writedump(row.ToString());
    writeoutput('<br><br><br>');
    row.select('##marker').remove();
    row.select("td:eq(0)").attr("rel", "nofollow");
//  writeoutput(image.toString());
}
```

1. i am trying to remove the last TD
2. I want to remove the Img and just use the text in the img tag like `title` or `alt`

Answer (score 2):

> 1. i am trying to remove the last TD
> 2. I want to remove the Img and just use the text in the img tag like title or alt

```
for( row in rows ){
  // get the first image object
  image = row.select( "img" )[ 1 ]
  // extract the alt or title text
  imageAlt = image.attr( "alt" )?:image.attr( "title" )?:""
  // replace the image with the extracted text
  image.parent().append( imageAlt )
  image.remove()
  //remove the last column
  row.select( "td" ).last().remove()
}
```